# JtextField shows text only on text selection

Tags: java, browser, applet, jpanel

Currently am working on applets where JTextField is used.But for some reason
sometimes the textfield doesn't display the text.Only when I try to select the text from the empty text box then it displays text.

Before [image: just after panel loads.]

After [image: after I try to select text]

I am using netbeans for coding.Tried some properties from properties tab of that component but no much help.

Can any one guess the issue?

Comment: Could you please provide an MCVE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Its only JPanel in JApplet on browser.I can these details only !

Comment: You have to post your code (method) where the text for the field is set. If you made it by typing in the text in netbeans properties editor, so please switch from design view to source view and copy & paste the folded code (unfold it first). The line of code maybe look like this `jTextField1.setText("TESTING NEW STUFF")`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx Guys,I got the answer it was another text box behind this one that caused loading problem.
Thanx a lot for support.
problem solved!

Answer (score -1):

you need to put the JTextfield.value equal to the value given. e.g: `String bla = JTextfield.value`. normally, that should be fixing it

Comment: there is no value method in JTextField api.

Comment: @jonathanmercken: Do you really know the answer or the Swing API?

Comment: i found the problem. you're using applets, which i didn't notice till now. what is the code of your actionlistener?

Comment: 1-, An ActionListener has nothing to do with displaying text in a text field.

Comment: Hi Guys, sorry there is no action performed event registered.Only parameters it takes from url and and other custom api.

Comment: I tried toady also.same result.I mean tested.Text gets displayed only when I select it.